# "An integer is required" datetime field

Tags: python, sql, django

what i wanted to do with this code is get all the datas thats dated older than yesterday. It throws an error "an integer is required" at the line:

> date = datetime.date(year, month, yesterday)

So far to my knowledge, its taking year as an integer but not month field. It takes the month field as the default datetime field.

Heres my view:

```
current = datetime.datetime.now()
yesterday = datetime.datetime.today() + datetime.timedelta(days = -1) 
year = datetime.date.today().year
month = datetime.date.today() + relativedelta(months = -1)
date = datetime.date(year, month, yesterday)
hist_obj = Events.objects.filter(uploader = request.user,
        start_date__lte = date)
return render_to_response('history.html', {'history_obj':hist_obj})
```

Comment: well if integer is required, convert the params to integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
day_ago = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
yesterday = datetime.datetime(day_ago.year, day_ago.month, day_ago.day)
hist_obj = Events.objects.filter(uploader = request.user,
        start_date__lt = yesterday)
return render_to_response('history.html', {'history_obj':hist_obj})
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is confusing. `yesterday` and `month` are both datetimes, because that's how you defined them in lines 2 and 4. So what are you trying to achieve in the code that throws the error? As the message says, you can't pass a datetime as the day or month parameter to construct another datetime. Especially as, surely, `yesterday` is already the date that you want? Why can't you simply pass that to the query?